# How to access HTML elements in ASPX menu page?

Tags: vba, forms, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to submit form details. I am unable to share HTML details so tried to explain below.

I have a menu control page `https://www.abcmenu.aspx`.
This page calls the url `https://www.abc-employee.aspx` using `javascript:void(0)`, which bring a form in same page when I click on employee menu item.

However, the page does not refresh nor does another page load, and the URL in the address bar remains unchanged.

Here is a sample view of the website:

[image: Website form screenshot]

I need to fill the form details and hit submit button.

The below code gives run time error stating object required.

```vba
Set htmldoc = ie.document

Dim emp as mshtml.ihtmlinputelement
Set emp = htmldoc.getelementbyid("fld_emp")
emp.value = 357690

Dim subm as mshtml.ihtmlelememt
Set subm = htmldoc.getelementbyid("btnk_sub")
Subm.click
```

I tried to `debug.print` all elements under form tag, but it does not return the elements in the form.

When I execute the code, it returns only the main menu page details and not form elements.

Here is the code I tried to print HTML elements

```vba
Dim htmla as mshtml.ihtmlelement 

Dim htmlas as mshtml.ihtmlelementcollection 

For each htmla in htmlas
    Debug.print htmla.innertext
Next htmla
```

**Why am I not able to access HTML elements inside form that was opened in the main menu page?**

[image: Page element structure]

Comment: Can you please inform us whether the employee page is getting load in an iframe or in a DIV or in any other element on the menu.aspx page? If it is an iframe then you need to switch to the iframe to access the element of the employee page. You can try to create a sample with dummy values that can help us to reproduce and test the issue. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way and we can try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: I think it is iframe based on what I see at the bottom of DOM. I have uploaded a sample picture of the navigation in html page to the bottom of my question which I believe will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access iframe elements on the ASP.Net web page using VBA then you can refer to the example below may help you to solve your issue.

```
Sub demo()
 
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
   
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   
    IE.Visible = True
    
    URL = "https://example.com"
 
    IE.navigate URL
    
    Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
 
    Dim elemCollection As IHTMLElementCollection
    
    Debug.Print (IE.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.getElementsByName("fname")(0).Value)
    
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT for informing me about iframe as it is a new learning.
I just edited your code to my requirements and it is working cooool